# Jquery datepicker set server date as default

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery datepicker from jqueryui.com and im  changing the calendar to 'fa'.It's 
work fine.I want to get today from server by ahax call(because date in client may be not be correct)and set as default.If i set default date to another date(not today) its work fine and date is highlighted correctly,but if date is today,date is not highlighted in calendar
I have this code:

```
$('#txtVacationStartDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'y/mm/dd',
});
```

This code from set default:

```
  $("#txtVacationstartSDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date("2014/06/05"));//not today and work fine(highlighted  in calendar)
  $("#txtVacationStartDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date("2014/06/06"));// today and not work(not highlighted  in calendar)
```

This code is  ajax Call

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "GetDataHandler.ashx?action=getDateTime",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function (dateResult) {
        $("#txtVacationStartDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date(dateResult)); //dateResult="2014/06/05"
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show us you AJAX call code. What does the AJAX call returns in response ?

Comment: @Illaya Do you understand my problem?My problem is highlighted today in calendar not get date from server

Comment: @RahulGupta I edit question and add ajax call.Ajax return Gregorian date of today.If result is not today.its work fine and highlight in calender but for today not highlight.

Comment: please provide the date !

Comment: I comment date in ajax call! ("2014/06/05").Ajax call returm today date. for today "2014/06/05"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved: This is an css issue, not related to JS or ajax

Today's date is always highlighted in Jquery datepicker with light yellow background and selected date is highlighted with white background.
Today's date has added class "ui-state-highlight" and selected date has added class "ui-state-active" .

By default "ui-state-highlight" class has higher precedence than "ui-state-active" in jquery-ui.css, that's why if today's date is set as selected date still it appears with yellow highlight.

To change the precedence add below class in your local css file and it will solve your problem.

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Js fiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sQ857/

Answer (score 0):

After the `AJAX` call completes, you will have to destroy the old instance of the datepicker and re-initialize it. Try the code bewlow:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GetDataHandler.ashx?action=getDateTime",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function (dateResult) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#txtVacationStartDate").datepicker( "destroy" );//destroy the existing datepicker instance
        //Re-initialize the date picker
        $('#txtVacationStartDate').datepicker({
             dateFormat: 'y/mm/dd',
        });
        $("#txtVacationStartDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date(dateResult)); //dateResult="2014/06/05"
     });
    }
});
```